# Difference between PhoneGap Build and locally building PhoneGap Android App

Tags: cordova, android-build, phonegap-build, construct-2

I'm using Construct2 (a GUI game IDE that simply gives ack HTML5 and JS) to develop a couple of games,

what I'm not figuring out is that, exporting a project from C2 to build it on PhoneGap Build
gives you the www folder that has to be zipped and uploaded to PhoneGap Build, and this just works.
If I want to build the app locally creating a PhoneGap android project, replacing the www gives me nothing more than a black screen.

so... Is there a difference between PhoneGap and PhoneGap build? Do i have to declare something different?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out why, there were two problems, 
one my fault and one apparently Scirra's fault.

1. in the **config.xml** root element **<\widget>** that contains the
   xml name space i have not seen the **id** attribute that needs to
   match the application package.
2. when you export from Construct2 for PhoneGap Build 
   you get a standard index.html page that targets to an
   ipotetical "phonegap.js" that surely is added by phonegap build but
   if your creating projects locally you get "cordova-2.X.X.js" and
   this breaks the game.

Answering the question for other readers purpose **Phonegap** and **Phonegap Build** work exactly the same way, just complain the standards!!

Comment: +1 for you thanks! In eclipse we need to replace jquery-1.7.1.min.js to query-1.7.1.js to avoid some errors!

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any difference really -- aside from the fact that obviously PhoneGap Build is easier to use :)

So the app is getting onto the device / simulator and just showing a blank screen?